# Elasticsearch (Opensearch) filter by string field length

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have a mapping like below, and I'd like to return back all docs where the "text" field has a length of 2 or less.

```
{
    "took": 181,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "asset_revision_structured_data",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "987785",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "doc": {
                        "prediction": {
                            "drugs": [
                                {
                                    "predictions": {
                                        "relevant_drugs": [
                                            {
                                                "start": 52,
                                                "end": 58,
                                                "label": "Drug Relevant",
                                                "text": "Idhifa",
```

I've tried

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "script": {
                    "script": "doc.prediction.drugs.predictions.relevant_drugs.text.length() < 3"
```

but it says

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "No field found for [prediction] in mapping with types []"
```

What am I doing wrong? Does the nesting affect how I'm supposed to define the script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because there are array types in your data as `[]`，you must use array like this: doc.prediction[0].drugs.predictions.relevant_drugs......

Comment: Unfortunately, that still gives the same error